# Minhag 3 times, source?

Tags: minhag, nedarim-shevuot, tractate-nedarim

In machzorim there is a nusach for hatarat nedarim, to annulate even "a good minhag that I did 3 times ..."

But what is source for this counting like a neder (or other type of engagement)?

Shulchan Aruch (YD 211) only talks about, someone who *restricted* himself from permitted thing? Not about *positive* behavior?

Comment: Note that in _hataras n'darim_ mentions _sh'vu'os_ also. Maybe the three-times-good-action thing is (like) a _sh'vu'a_ rather than (like) a _neder_?

Comment: If that's what you meant, you should [edit] the question to say so. Nobody can be expected to read the comments to find out what you meant.

Comment: Why can't a restriction be a good Minhag that you did three times?

Comment: Also, what do you mean when you ask, "what is the source for this counting like a neder (or other type of engagement)?" Are you only looking for a book citation or what is the reason for the concept?

Comment: @YaacovDeane Rather the former. But a good reason could also count as a 'source' (think אבעית אימא קרא אבעית אימא סברא !)

Comment: @DoubleAA Difficult to consider a restriction a 'good minhag'. Nedarim and consort are generally considered a bad thing (Nedarim 9a כנדרי רשעים, 22a כאילו בנה במה ... ) (Nedarim 7a נזיר חוטא)

Comment: @yO_ but also עשו סיג לתורה and המחמיר תבוא עליו ברכה. Clearly not all restrictions are bad and not all are good. That's why we specify that this is a good one.